# Undefined reference to main error very persistent

Tags: c, linux, eclipse

I'm using the Eclipse Oxygen IDE on Linux, and I am trying to code in C. There are some problems though.

Whatever code I try to build, even perfectly valid code, returns this error:

```
make all 
Building target: heyson
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc  -o "heyson"  ./heyson.o   
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
makefile:29: recipe for target 'heyson' failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [heyson] Error 1
```

This is all of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){ 
    printf("hello");    
    return 0;
}
```

It's literally a hello-world program. I tried putting `main(void)`, but that returned the same error, I tried removing the #include line but that kept it the same, I did nigh everything possible to this and it keeps spitting out the same thing.

All I did, was install the C/C++ version of eclipse, use the Linux GCC toolchain to create a project, create a source file called heyson.c, and put this code in, trying to build it. After some time I realised that everything I put in returned the same thing, so I'm at the point of desperation...

**UPDATE:** I decided to uninstall Eclipse and use CLion instead. It works brilliantly, so I can only conclude that the problem was the IDE itself.

Comment: Show your makefile please.

Comment: Do I paste the entirety of it in the post or? It seems pretty long. Also found it in the debug folder of the program.

Comment: Is it an automatically generated Makefile?

Comment: Yes it is automatically generated, from what I can tell.

Comment: At a guess, your IDE does not recognize the source file as part of the project, and therefore is not building it.  In particular, if removing the `#include` statement did not cause at least one compiler warnings to be generated then the code you modified was probably not compiled at all.  This would be an IDE problem, not a C problem.

Comment: I guess I'm screwed if that's the case...

Comment: You can post an image of your project structure (carefully, though. People don't like images here :) )

Comment: SInce they don't, it looks like a folder that contains a heyson.c file, along with another folder saying debug. If that's not enough I'll try uploading a photo.